# Parseerror pushing data to python script with ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, apache, cgi

I’m trying to send data with Ajax to a python script, but I keep getting a "parsererror" and a responseText that returns the python script.

I have tried all sorts of combinations like {"data": "data"}, {data: "data"}, {data: data}, etc but nothing works.

Maybe you can see the problem

**Ajax**

```
var data = {
    id: '20',
    action: 'Test'
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./cgi-bin/datahandler.py",
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
});
```

**Python**

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u
import cgi, cgitb

cgitb.enable()

data = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "The id data is: " + data["id"].value
print "<br />"
print "The action data is: " + data["action"].value
print "<br />"
print data
```

**Apache**

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/wamp/www/cgi-bin/"
AddHandler cgi-script .py

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**The response text**

```
"#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u import cgi, cgitb cgitb.enable() data = cgi.FieldStorage() print "Content-Type: text/html\n" print "The id data is: " + data["id"].value print "<br />" print "The action data is: " + data["action"].value print "<br />" print data"
```

Comment: Where do you get the error ? In python side ?

Comment: @RobertoSánchez error: function(response) gives the parse error and return the content of the python script

Comment: So, you get the python code, that is `import cgi, ...`, not the expected output, right?

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, the problem seems related with the CGI config in your web server, that is managing your python file as static file not as CGI.

Take a look to this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

You need to add to your python CGI file this line (or an equivalent one in your Win system):

```
#!c:/Python30/python.exe -u
```

The CGI config in apache could be something like:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/wamp/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/cgi-bin/">
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Options +ExecCGI
   AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

Be sure that you load the module_cgi before the directory configuration.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I'm getting desperate

Comment: Try to put `Options +ExecCGI` and `AddHandler...` and the end of `<directory>` directive

Comment: Be sure that you load the module_cgi before the directory configuration.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: :-(, Just a silly test, try to modify the script alias to `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin2/ "c:/wamp/www/cgi-bin/"` And modify the ajax request properly.

Answer (score 0):

What does http://jsonlint.com/ say about your data?
It might not be the solution.